# Jssor option for unique url per image?

Tags: image-gallery, jssor

I'm wanting to use jssor gallery with arrow navigation, but one thing I need is that each image in the gallery must have a unique url when it is selected, so that people can link to that specific image in the gallery. I looked through the options, but didn't see anything like this. Is there an option for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><a href="url"><img u="image" src="image.jpg" /></a></div>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html

**Edit:**

```
<div><img u="image" src="http://example.com/gallery/01" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="http://example.com/gallery/02" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="http://example.com/gallery/03" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="http://example.com/gallery/04" /></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I'm not sure if this is exactly what I'm looking for. To be more precise, what I want is for the urls of the gallery to be something like `http://example.com/gallery/01` for the first image, then `http://example.com/gallery/02` for the next image, and so on. It looks like the method you mention makes the image clickable? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I see, it's not a question of jssor slider. You can get your html code ready before you initialize jssor slider.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite know what you mean when you say that I can get my html code ready before I initialize jssor slider. Wouldn't I need to do something in jssor to generate the changing urls?